# Are orthogonal positive semidefinite matrices each with trace equal to one necessarily rank-one projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal, positive-semidefinite

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $P_1,\dots,P_n\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a collection of positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrices satisfying the following properties:

- $\operatorname{Tr}P_i=1$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$
- $P_iP_j = 0$ whenever $i\neq j$.

It is necessarily the case that there is an orthonormal basis $u_1,\dots,u_n$ such that $P_i = u_i u_i^*$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$?

---

My thoughts:

- The matrices $P_1,\dots,P_n$ are normal and commuting, so they are simultaneously diagonalizable. In particular, we might as well assume without loss of generality that the are diagonal.

Comment: Did you mean $\operatorname{Tr}(P_iP_j) = 0$?

Comment: No, but $\mathrm{Tr}(PQ)=0$ if and only if $PQ=0$ for any positive semidefinite matrices $P$ and $Q$ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've gotten to the point where they are diagonal. Note that a product of diagonal matrices is $0$ iff they do not share non-zero entries, i.e. for any $i \neq j$ and $1 \leq k \leq n$ we get $(P_i)_{k,k} \neq 0 \Rightarrow (P_j)_{k,k} = 0$. Use the pigeon hole principle to conclude.